# how to make a radautocompletetextview with prefilled using nativescript-angular

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-angular

how to make a radautocompletetextview with prefilled using nativescript-angular?

This is how i am trying to do it:

HTML:

```
<RadAutoCompleteTextView id="rice-cake" (didAutoComplete)="onTokenSelected($event)" marginTop="40px" style="border-width:0.5;border-radius:5px;border-color:#E6E6E6;"
                            #autocmp [items]="dataItems" suggestMode="Suggest" displayMode="Plain">
                            <SuggestionView tkAutoCompleteSuggestionView suggestionViewHeight="150">
                      `enter code here`<ng-template tkSuggestionItemTemplate let-item="item">
                                    <StackLayout orientation="vertical" padding="10">
                                        <Label [text]="item.text"></Label>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ng-template>
                            </SuggestionView>
                        </RadAutoCompleteTextView>
```

TypeScript:

```
 this.autocomplete = 
          <RadAutoCompleteTextView>view.getViewById(this.page,"rice-cake");  
                console.log(JSON.stringify(this.autocomplete))
                var token = new TokenModel(_result.dish, undefined);
                this.autocomplete.addToken(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this out:

https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/323